# Swift Dictionary in UILocalNotification userinfo

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, swift, uilocalnotification

I don't understand why XCode returns me the error "'@lvalue $T7' is not identical to (NSObject, AnyObject)'" when i try to set the userinfo dictionary of a UILocalNotification. Here is the sample:

```
var medicine: String?
var notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.userInfo["medicine"] = medicine
```

It's not the first time i have problems with dictionary. I don't understand what apple changed with the xcode 6 beta 3.

I've tryed to a lot of casting but i can't understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are creating a new UILocalNotification so its `userInfo` is nil; there is nothing there to cast. You have to create the `userInfo` as some definite Swift dictionary type if you want to treat it as a Swift dictionary (as you are attempting to do). Also, you need an actual value for `medicine`, not just an uninitialized type. For example:

```
var userInfo = [String:String]()
let medicine = "SomeMedicine"
userInfo["medicine"] = medicine
notification.userInfo = userInfo
```

Comment: i have 2 questions: 1) what if i have the var medicine not initialized yet? 2) have i got just String type key-value for my dctionary? can i have string-int key value for example?

Comment: (1) makes no sense. If you don't have the var `medicine` then you cannot construct the `userInfo` dictionary, so why are we here? (2) It's Swift. If you want a Swift dictionary, you must declare a dictionary of _one type_. But of course, since this dictionary is destined to be handed over to Objective-C, that type can be `AnyObject`.